# Can Apache2 be configured to store a part of the access log on a separate location?

Tags: apache-2.2

We plan to use a [tracking pixel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_bug) to collect some analytics. It would be very helpful to configure a different policy for storing access logs to this pixel (http://ourdomain.com/tracking.png?someParameter=123)

Can Apache be configured to filter and store only the access logs that contain a specific URL pattern on a different location than the main access log? We still want to keep the full access log on the initial partition, with a different retention policy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [mod_setenvif](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_setenvif.html) to set an environment variable related to your tracking pixel and then filter the logs using it. something like

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "tracking\.png$" tracking
.
.
.

CustomLog logs/access_log common env=!tracking
CustomLog logs/tracking_access_log common env=tracking
```

If the tracking pixel is requested then the environment variable gets set and the event gets logged to a different file.